# Cleanest way to find objects matching certain criteria in a java.util.List?

Tags: java, list

I could write myself a helper class that does this when given a functor, but I was wondering if there's a better approach, or if there's something already in the standard library (seems like there should be).

Answers I've found on StackOverflow are all for C# which doesn't help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - there isn't. Apache `commons-collections` has predicates for this sort of thing but the resultant code (using anonymous inner classes) is usually ugly and a pain to debug.

Just use a basic **for-loop** until they bring [closures](http://javac.info) into the language

Comment: Ok, I keep hearing conflicting information on this point: are closures in Java 7 or not? I see some pages saying they didn't make the cut and others saying they did.

Comment: I think at the moment the answer is that, yes, they will probably make it. Google Neal Gafter for more info!

Answer (score 3):

By using the [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) library, for example you could find the top reputation users as it follows:

```
List<User> topUsers = 
    select(users, having(on(User.class).getReputation(), greaterThan(20000)));
```

It has some advantages respect the Quaere library because it doesn't use any magic string, it is completely type safe and in my opinion it offers a more readable DSL.

Answer (score 3):

[Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) provides this functionality as well via its Collections module. I am biased since I am the maintainer of the module, but I believe given the constraints of Java 6 this is an option.

With Java 7 there will be closures which enable filtering via closures, which makes usage of external libraries less necessary.

Comment: Why is this being flagged as spam where as other very similar answers aren't? This is just as valid as some of the other answers.

Comment: You may be interested in this thread on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50038/it-doesnt-matter-what-the-question-is-theres-only-one-answer

Answer (score 2):

There is [JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Quaere](http://quaere.codehaus.org/). I didn't use it but it looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Collection Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) offers this kind of helper method, a bit more cleanly than commons-collections.

Comment: The "cleanliness" is a result of the Google collections lib being generics-aware, unlike commons collections.